# How to get the access token from the redirect_uri?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, basecamp

I am creating a web based application and want to get data from Basecamp using their API through OAuth2. 
I have successfully redirected my page to this link my redirect_uri, but I couldnt get any access token from the page.

How to get the access token using the flask application that I have created?
Any code samples will be much appreciated.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'basecamp_token' in session:
        ret = remote.get('email')
        return jsonify(ret.data)
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('redirecturl'))

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return basecamp.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))

@app.route('/authorized')
@basecamp.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: error=%s' % (
            request.args['error']
        )
    if 'basecamp_token' in resp:
        # session['example_oauth'] = resp
        print(resp)
        return jsonify(resp)
    return str(resp)

@app.route("/redirecturl")
def redirecturl():
    return redirect('http://basecamp.com/oauth2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret'
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```